# 100% height on absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have responsive 'cells' in my WP website created by the posts.

**HTML**

```
<article>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'row'); ?> >

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-cell">
                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <h3><?php the_category(' '); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /#post -->

</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 18% 0;
}

.text-cell {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I don't want the 'article' to have a set height if possible (I used padding to create a dynamic height for 'article')

I want 'text-cell' to be full height of the article and 30% of the width. Until its mobile then it'll be full width and 30% of the height. The 100% height doesn't seem to work.

visual ex. 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set height 100% on absolute div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217783/set-height-100-on-absolute-div)

Comment: Doesn't your current code work? http://jsfiddle.net/fzwqn3uh/2/

Comment: i thought is should, but my 'background-color' doesn't show. But I want it to work like your fiddle shows

Comment: Well then your framework is causing the issue, there is probably a lot more css on the element

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `bottom` to your positioning scheme:

```
.text-cell {
  position: absolute;
  /* height: 100%; <-- remove this */
  width: 30%;
  bottom: 0; /* <-- add this */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

If that doesn't work than there is an issue with the height of the `.col-md-12` DIV or the `article` DIV.

Comment: i've added bottom and it doesn't work, '.col-md-12' is a bootstrap function that only makes columns (doesn't deal with heights) and thats the only style for article. The text inside 'text-cell' is vertically centred, but the background doesn't show up at all (indicting issue with height)