# How do I tile a div background in css to fill my html on every screen?

Tags: html, css, background, repeat, viewport

I have an html that looks like this:

```
<body>
stuff here that scrolls past the viewport
</body>

<div class="bgimg"> repeated image made with blurred css filter here </div>
```

and css that looks like this:

```
.bgimg {
    
        background: url(urlhere.gif);
        
        filter: blur(15px);
    
        -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
    
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    
        background-repeat: repeat;
    
        position: absolute;
    
        top: 0;  
        
        bottom: 0;
        
        width: 100%;
    
        height: 100%;
    
        z-index: -1;
    
}
```

I made a separate background image so i can blur it using css and not have my body blurred out as well.

My problem is when I set the size of the div in my CSS with a repeat function, it only goes as far as the viewport window and does not repeat all the way down to the bottom of my html. Is there a way to make this div as big as the html so when I scroll down I still see my background repeat?

Comment: Any other stuff in your HTML? As a test in fiddle don't show anything wrong. Although I did use a different image from the code. If you could provide a fiddle that would help alot.

Answer (score 0):

Firsly, put your div *inside* of your body, then make the position of the body relative. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217832/10223638) has a good explanation why this works.

```
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 3000px; <!-- Added for testing purposes -->
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then, change your `background-size: 100% 100%;` to `background-size: 100%` as setting the y axis to 100% cause the image to stretch instead of actually repeating.

Also, altough it might not be necessary, you could set the background to only repeat vertically `background-repeat: repeat-y;` if you don't want it to horizontally repeat.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to use view width and view height or screen:

```
{   
    background-size:100vw;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```